# Is there unstack in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

There is [np.stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) in [NumPy](https://numpy.org/), but is there an opposite `np.unstack` same as [tf.unstack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack)?

Comment: Look at the code for `np.stack`.  It expands the dimension of all inputs, and does a concatenate.  `np.split` might do what you want; I haven't used it much.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, [np.split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) helped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Coming across this late, here is a much simpler answer:

```
def unstack(a, axis=0):
    return np.moveaxis(a, axis, 0)
#    return list(np.moveaxis(a, axis, 0))
```

As a bonus, the result is still a numpy array. The unwrapping happens if you just python-unwrap it:

```
A, B, = unstack([[1, 2], [3, 4]], axis=1)
assert list(A) == [1, 3]
assert list(B) == [2, 4]
```

Unsurprisingly, it is also the fastest:

```
# np.squeeze
❯ python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; a=np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(1000), np.arange(1000)));" "C = [np.squeeze(e, 1) for e in np.split(a, a.shape[1], axis = 1)]"
100 loops, best of 5: 2.64 msec per loop
    
# np.take
❯ python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; a=np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(1000), np.arange(1000)));" "C = [np.take(a, i, axis = 1) for i in range(a.shape[1])]"       
50 loops, best of 5: 5.08 msec per loop

# np.moveaxis
❯ python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; a=np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(1000), np.arange(1000)));" "C = np.moveaxis(a, 1, 0)"
100000 loops, best of 5: 3.89 usec per loop

# list(np.moveaxis)
❯ python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; a=np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(1000), np.arange(1000)));" "C = list(np.moveaxis(a, 1, 0))"
1000 loops, best of 5: 205 usec per loop
```

Comment: The question was to make an opposite of `np.stack` and np.stack joins a python list of arrays along new axis. So the opposite should return a python list of arrays, not single array. That's why other answers are a bit verbose and more slowly - because they produce a list. But thanks for nice try! UpVoting your answer. If you extend your answer to produce a list and do timings with list version then it would be nice and exactly what np.unstack is about.

Comment: Also your timings are not very correct. You include into timing both importing numpy module and creating array of meshgrid. For correct timings you should split out this part into separate preparation stage, and leave only unstacking function inside timing code. And do more iterations.

Comment: Actually I think that having non-list variant is also nice. Just to be precise and fair in your timings compared to other functions you have to timeit all variants with list conversion. Just do `list(unstack(...))` for your function in you timings and you'll get what's needed.

Comment: If you want a list, feel free to call list(unstack(...)) or do it in the function. I do prefer getting back a numpy array.

Comment: You're right about the timings - I updated to include a setup step.

Comment: Changed just now Accepted answer from my to yours, because your solution works much faster than my, and also looks much more simple (and has more UpVotes)! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097426/is-there-unstack-in-numpy/64097936#comment113345633_64097426) of @hpaulj solved task efficiently using [np.split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64097426#main.py)

```
import numpy as np

def unstack(a, axis = 0):
    return [np.squeeze(e, axis) for e in np.split(a, a.shape[axis], axis = axis)]

a = [np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]), np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])]

for axis in range(len(a[0].shape) + 1):
    b = np.stack(a, axis)
    c = unstack(b, axis)
    # Check that we have same "c" as input "a"
    assert len(c) == len(a) and all(np.all(sc == sa) for sc, sa in zip(c, a)), (c, a)
```

Answer (score 3):

it's simple like:

```
list(array)
```

it will iterate over the first axis.

an example:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
c = np.stack([a,b])
d = list(c)
```

Output of `c`

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Output of `d`

```
[array([1,2,3]), array([4,5,6])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also be solved using [np.take](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html).

It is a simpler than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64097936/941531) solution but could be a bit less efficient, needs timing measurement for different inputs.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64097426var3#main.py)

```
import numpy as np

def unstack(a, axis = 0):
    return [np.take(a, i, axis = axis) for i in range(a.shape[axis])]

a = [np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]), np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])]

for axis in range(len(a[0].shape) + 1):
    b = np.stack(a, axis)
    c = unstack(b, axis)
    # Check that we have same "c" as input "a"
    assert len(c) == len(a) and all(np.all(sc == sa) for sc, sa in zip(c, a)), (c, a)
```